# Marionette Nested CompositeViews and Change Events Either not firing or happening in reverse

Tags: marionette

**tl;dr
http://jsfiddle.net/fRTBU/2/**

Have a Marionette App that I am showing a list of Baseball Cities.

```
window.teams = new MyApp.Models.TeamCollection([
        { League : "AL", City : "Boston"  , TeamId : 1 },
        { League : "AL", City : "Chicago" , TeamId : 2 },
        { League : "NL", City : "Chicago" , TeamId : 3 }
        ]);
```

I want to have  a list of the cities broken down by league.

something like :

```
<table>
<tr>
   <td> 
     <h2>AL</h2>
     <ul>
        <li>Boston 1 </li>
        <li>Chicago 2</li>
     </ul>
   </td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td> 
     <h2>NL</h2>
     <ul>
        <li>Chicago 3 </li>
     </ul>
   </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I can get that to render.

But when I try to add a new team (For expansion  :P)

```
window.teams.push(new MyApp.Models.Team({ League : "NL", 
                                            City : "Washington", 
                                          TeamId : 4 }));
```

The collection change events don't fire ( in the JSFiddle )

http://jsfiddle.net/fRTBU/2/

```
collectionEvents: {
    "reset": "myFunc"  ,
    "change" : "myFunc", 
    "add" : "myFunc"
},
myFunc: function () {
    Logger('myFunc');
    var grid = window.teams.groupBy(function (row) {
        return row.get("League");
    });
    this.collection = new Backbone.Collection(_.toArray(grid));
}
```

or in my app (with more logic surrounding it )

```
ReferenceError: TeamId is not defined
```

main app structure

```
MyApp.Models.Team = Backbone.Model.extend({
    idAttribute: 'TeamId'
});

MyApp.Models.TeamCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: MyApp.Models.Team
});

MyApp.Views.ListItemView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    tagName: 'tr',
    template : '#row-template'
});

MyApp.Views.ListCompositeView = Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
    itemView: MyApp.Views.ListItemView,
    template: "#list-template",
    itemViewContainer: "ul",
    initialize: function () {
        this.collection = new Backbone.Collection(
                                  _.toArray(this.model.attributes));
    },
    onRender: function () {
        $(this.$el).find("h2.ListHead")
                   .html(this.collection.models[0].get('League'));
    }
});

MyApp.Views.TableView = Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
    itemView: MyApp.Views.ListCompositeView,
    tagName: "table",
    itemViewContainer: "tbody",
    template: "#table-template",
    initialize : function () {
       this.myFunc();
    },
    collectionEvents: {
        "reset": "myFunc"  ,
        "change" : "myFunc", 
        "add" : "myFunc"
    },
    myFunc: function () {
        Logger('myFunc');
        var grid = window.teams.groupBy(function (row) {
            return row.get("League");
        });
        this.collection = new Backbone.Collection(_.toArray(grid));
    }
});
```

When I say they are happening in reverse it appears as though the `MyApp.Views.ListItemView` gets a collection and `MyApp.Views.ListCompositeView` gets a model.

**JsFiddle Link Again 
http://jsfiddle.net/fRTBU/2/**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so there are a few issues here. The reason your events aren't firing in the `TableView` is because you break the event bindings to the `window.teams` collection when you replace its collection with `this.collection = new Backbone.Collection(_.toArray(grid));` -- at that point its collection is no longer `window.teams`.

Another issue is that you're trying to display the data as if it were modeled like:

```
Leagues
   |______League
   |         |______Team
   |         |______Team
   |
   |______League
             |______Team
             |______Team
             |______Team
```

... but your data is coming in structured like:

```
  Teams
   |______Team
   |______Team
   |______Team
```

One solution would be to have a `TeamCollection` that accepts your data in the `{ League : "AL", City : "Boston" , TeamId  : 1 }` format, and to bind change events to a function that updates a `LeagueTeamsCollection` per league, and use that collection as the basis for 2 view classes: a `CompositeView` and an `ItemView`.

Comment: Looks like you got me a good direction thanks!  http://jsfiddle.net/fRTBU/6/ for a working demo